# How to calculate index of thumbnail when carousel wraps but index continues to increase?

Tags: math, jcarousel

This is really more of a math question I think...

I am working with an older version of a JavaScript carousel library called jcarousel. It takes a list of images and turns it into a carousel/slideshow. It supports a wrapping feature where, as you click through to the last image, it wraps around to the beginning of the slideshow. I'm using a callback function which receives the current index of the image displayed in the list of all the images in the carousel. However, when you get to the end of the carousel, and it starts over, the index is not reset to the beginning, it just continues to increase.

Here's an example...Let's say I have 5 images in my carousel. The index starts at 1 (not 0). When the carousel gets to image5, the next image displayed is image1, but the index is 6. Likewise, going the other direction, the index is decremented.

```
-1. image4
0. image5
1. image1
2. image2
3. image3
4. image4
5. image5
6. image1
7. image2
```

How can I calculate the index so that it stays within the range of my thumbnail indexes? For example:

- when index == -1 // the index should be 4 since it is displaying image4
- when index == 1 // the index can be 1, that's fine. I can easily subtract 1 to be 0-based index
- when index == 6 // the index should be 1 since it is displaying image1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulo function. Assume `numImg` contains the total number of images, you get the right number by calculating

```
 (index + numImg) % numImg
```

Adding numImg to index ensures that -1 is handled, the modulo (%) numImg calculates the remainder of division, thus the result is between 0 and numImg.

Comment: Ah, I thought it would involve that modulo thing. Thanks!